# Spring boot @DataJpaTest configured with Oracle database not fetching data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Boot. I am trying to configure the Junit Test for Spring Boot Repository. Below are the code snippet and configuration.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= ObjectAddressDaoImpl.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=AutoConfigureTestDatabase.class)
@TestPropertySource("/application.properties")
public class AddressTest{

   @Autowired
   private AddressDao daoAddress;

   @Test
   public void testGetAddresses() {
     List<AddressEntity> addresses = daoAddress.getAddresses(99L);
     System.out.println("Addresses : " + addresses.size());
   }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:Port:schema
spring.datasource.username=abcs
spring.datasource.password=abcs

spring.profiles.active=oracle

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

When I run the test it prints 0.

Kindly let me know if my configuration is correct. Any timely help appreciated!

Comment: If it prints 0 and doesn't crash, it's probably correct. And if it prints 0, it's probably that the query executed by getAddresses(99L) doesn't return any row. You chose to omit code, since what you posted wouldn't even compile and since we don't know anything about the object and method being tested, so we can't help much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly @Autowire the daoAddress bean into your test class so connection is properly established. If logging has been enabled, please share the logger output as well.

Comment: I missed to add the Autowire the dao object. Now I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

It prints 0 because daoAddress.getAddress() is not returning anything.
you can put a debug pointer and check on that.

So for the test you need to write asserts in  your test method  and check for the proper output 
example :-

```
assertTrue("A/Wing",daoAddress.getAddress());
```

Next you can autowire your dao class , also you can  use mokito for test

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-junit-5-mockito/

This Link will help you to understand the test in spring.